# abs(v) faster than (v + mask) ^ mask in python?

Tags: python

According to [this page](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs), one way to compute the integer absolute value (`abs`) without branching in [c](/questions/tagged/c) is as follows:

```c
int v;           // we want to find the absolute value of v
unsigned int r;  // the result goes here 
int const mask = v >> sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1;

r = (v + mask) ^ mask;
```

Out of curiosity, I wanted to compare it with `abs()` function in Python:

```
> python -m timeit "v = -13" "r = abs(v)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.119 usec per loop
> python -m timeit "v = -13" "mask = v >> 23" "r = (v + mask)^mask"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.18 usec per loop
```

It seems the `abs()` has better performance than bitwise operations. Why? Or am I missing something in my test code?

More information about the above test codes:

`mask = v >> 23`, because of the size of `v` is `24` through `sys.getsizeof(v)`.

Comment: Remember there's a whole abstraction layer of Python objects between your code and the underlying C (assuming CPython) code. Micro-optimisations like bit hacking therefore aren't a reliable way to improve performance.

Comment: Similarly `sys.getsizeof` tells you about the size of the Python object, not the number of bits required to represent the integer.

Answer (score 4):

IPython Notebook simplifies timing. All code directly after `%%timeit` is setup code. I took out the assignment to  `v` also:

```
%%timeit v = -13
abs(v)

10000000 loops, best of 3: 94.8 ns per loop


%%timeit v = -13;mask = v >> 23
(v + mask)^mask

1000000 loops, best of 3: 182 ns per loop
```

Looks like `abs` is really twice as fast.

Looking at the byte code can help to get feeling what is going on:

```
import dis
```

for `abs`:

```
dis.dis("""
v = -13
r = abs(v)""")

 2           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (-13)
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (v)

  3           6 LOAD_NAME                1 (abs)
              9 LOAD_NAME                0 (v)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 STORE_NAME               2 (r)
             18 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

and for the other approach:

```
dis.dis("""
v = -13
mask = v >> 23
r = (v + mask)^mask
""")

  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (-13)
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (v)

  3           6 LOAD_NAME                0 (v)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (23)
             12 BINARY_RSHIFT
             13 STORE_NAME               1 (mask)

  4          16 LOAD_NAME                0 (v)
             19 LOAD_NAME                1 (mask)
             22 BINARY_ADD
             23 LOAD_NAME                1 (mask)
             26 BINARY_XOR
             27 STORE_NAME               2 (r)
             30 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             33 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Also note that the binary operators might again cause (expensive!) method lookups, as those operators could have been overriden if the types are not built-in. I am not sure whether the python compiler is able to infer it in this case.

Comment: I don't see what useful information the bytecode provides. It's just a direct translation of the Python. You still don't know what the `abs` function does, for example.